# How to use RxSwift for Objective-C and Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, rx-swift

A project was created in Objective-C language and later I used Swift in it. In my pod-file I have couple of Objective-C pods. I tried using RxSwift pod, it didn't allow me to have Swift pods and moreover I can't use `use_frameworks!` because I have Objective-C pods in it.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
# use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do   
  pod 'STPopup'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
  pod 'Reachability'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'CCHMapClusterController'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.8.2'
  pod 'DateTools'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'SpinKit', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'GPUImage'
  pod 'LLSimpleCamera', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
  pod 'JSONModel'
  pod 'ASIHTTPRequest'
  pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor', :git => 'https://github.com/luyzdeleon/PEPhotoCropEditor'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper', :git => 'https://github.com/luyzdeleon/RSKImageCropper'
  pod 'MXParallaxHeader'
  pod 'Toast', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'TransformerKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FRHyperLabel', '~> 1.0.1'
  pod 'STTweetLabel', :git => 'https://github.com/pabelnl/STTweetLabel.git', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'STTwitter'
  pod 'YSTutorialViewController'
  pod 'CTAssetsPickerController', :git => 'https://github.com/pabelnl/CTAssetsPickerController', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'RDHCollectionViewGridLayout', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'AFNetworking+RetryPolicy'
  pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics', '~> 2.4'
  pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout'
  pod 'BBBadgeBarButtonItem'
  pod 'FMDB'
  pod 'APAddressBook'
  pod 'CTVideoPlayerView'
  pod 'IBProgressButton'
  pod 'VIMVideoPlayer', :git => 'https://github.com/pabelnl/VIMVideoPlayer', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'ICGVideoTrimmer'
  pod 'CRGradientNavigationBar', :git => 'https://github.com/luyzdeleon/CRGradientNavigationBar', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'KILabel', '~> 1.0.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'SwiftTryCatch'
  pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
  pod 'IGListKit'
  pod 'SDWebImage-CircularProgressView'
  pod 'RxSwift'
end
```

- **Error i am getting with out `use_frameworks!`:**

[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: RxSwift

- **Error with `use_frameworks!`:**

[!] Unable to integrate the following embedded targets with their respective host targets (a host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target like a framework or extension):

- MyProject (true) and share (false) do not both set use_frameworks!.

Comment: Can you show your pod file? and are you using bridging header?

Comment: Yes i am using bridging header file.

Comment: what is the error you are facing

Comment: @Shabirjan  Added the error message.

Comment: so when you use pod install, what happens?

Comment: Please check the edited question,  error message i am getting when i use pod install without use_frameworks! and pod install  with use_frameworks!.

Comment: Hi, i created Project using ObjC than added a Swift file, created bridging header and than i added all the pods you mentioned and installed, and all pods installed easily without any error and i used use_framework as well

Comment: Can you please share the project which you created? And what is the cocoapod version you are using?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4smrbq6gy24epkq/PodExample.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Amit89 did you got solution for your issue, because I am also facing same issue now.

Comment: @Shabirjan, I tried as you suggested way, but for me, objective c existing api showing the following error while compile time, ld: library not found for -myApi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you try my demo project i shared?

Comment: @Shabirjan, thank you for your time and sharing a sample.  I tried your sample it works in sample only, but in my project it is not working. It seems like there is some something which i am missing in Xcode project setting. Right now i am focusing on some other parts and later i have to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `use_frameworks!` even if you have Objective-C pods in it.

Comment: I can use but i am getting error and project doesn't run.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Edited for better clarity.